# Python Tk Multiple Buttons Creation Problem

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm creating ten buttons and the button texts are labelled 1 to 10. The following code creates 10 buttons and labels correctly. But it's printing 9  as the output for all the buttons. What I expect it to do is to print the corresponding number of the Button to screen, So for Example if the user presses  Button 2 then it should print 2.

```
def create():
for i in range (1,10):
    lst.insert(i,Button(text=i,command=lambda: prnt(i)).pack())
```

(Note: 'prnt(i)' is a function that simply prints the value i has.
       'lst' is a list that stores the created buttons.)

From the output I can say that the program is using the latest i value as the argument for the function when user presses a button, So how would I solve this without having to write 10 lines of code for each buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (note the named argument to the lambda):

```
def create():
    for i in range (1,10):
        lst.insert(i,Button(text=i,command=lambda i=i : prnt(i)).pack())
```

This passes the *value* of i to the lambda as a local variable. Without this, you are using a reference to the original variable which will, of course, always resolve to whatever is stored in the original variable.

Comment: Thank you very much, That solved the problem.
I'm new to Python and was using lambda without knowing how it's doing things. Thanks again for the help :)